# Arduino button interrupt triggered on high power switch on

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have a nearly finished prototype using an arduino uno. Basically its purpose is to switch a 2000w main AC heating load using a heavy relay on and off. The input of the relay is comming from the mains but is connected to the power company using a special meter that is only switched on between 23-07 hrs at night. The power for the arduino is continous by the way, so this stays on.

The whole thing is nicely build into a box with on the front an small lcd display and a button, connected using 20cm wires to the arduino board (I am using a protoshield).

The button is pulled up with a 10k resistor which is pulled to ground when pressed. I have put a 0.47 uF cap on the input pin = pin 2 to also debounce the circuit a bit. In software I am using an interupt on the falling edge to detect button presses. The whole thing works nicely... Except...:

When the load ac input is switched on by the power company this is sometimes recognized as a button press! I am thinking that the suddon power spike induces a voltage in the 20 cm button wires which is recognized as a falling edge. How can I avoid this?

I am equiped with multimeter, oscilloscope, soldering... so I can try out any suggestions in detail.

Comment: The solution to this problem will more than likely include filtering hardware, I would ask here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use the oscilloscope (hope it's digital) to see the actual waveform. Probably it's an induction on the button wires, so the first thing I'd try (since you already filtered it with the debouncing circuit) is to shield the cables (you can try with an aluminum foil soldered to ground only on the board (not on the button side) or use shielded cables

Comment: my scope is indeed digital so I will measure this in the next couple of days, using a shielded cable also was my next idea, lets see how it goes :)

Comment: I replaced the wire running to the button with a fully shielded wire and of course connected the shield to ground. Unfortunately this did not solve the problem. I indeed see spikes on the lines when the AC is switching. I have now found out that I can easily simulate the issue by playing around with the input AC connector (creating some sparking contact on the input). My next move will be to add a snubber network just in parallel over the input AC. I let you know how it goes...

Comment: By the way, I solution that would indeed most probably work is to replace the mechanical contact relay with a solid state version that switching on the zero crossing of the AC. However since I have a heavy load (10 A @ 240 V AC) the SSR would dissipate to mach heat for my enclosure so I want to stick with the mechanical relay and see if the snugger network does the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to solve this issue in hardware, but unfortunately failed.
These are the options I tried, but that did NOT work

1. used a shielded cable for the button
2. implemented an XY denoise capacitor network on the AC of the load (input)
   like this one : http://www.conrad.be/ce/nl/product/450571/K042201052-Ontstoringscondensator-XY-Radiaal-bedraad-01-F-250-VAC-1-stuks?ref=searchDetail

In the end I implemented the following *software* solution:

The first time the button is pressed, it must be pressed 1 second before the button actually becomes active. This will never happen due to the AC turning on because this is a very brief spike. I programmed this into the arduino using interrupt to detect button press and then micro delay (inside the ISR) to check that after 1 seconds the button is still pressed.

After the initial 1 second button press, the button stays lively for 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem building a fuel injection flow bench. The button press starts a simulated engine run sequence that powers a relay. That relay then powers up to 6 injectors. What happens is as soon as I press the button the injectors closing induces a current and trips the whole system to start over again. The solution I've found that worked was using a battery to supply voltage to the injectors as opposed to the power supply itself. This isolates the arduino supply from the injector supply via my relay. The problem is of course now I need to keep the battery charged. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.